# How to add Swift and React Native ui-kit in the Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, uikit

My company has bought [Dynamic Layer ui-kit](https://www.dynamiclayer.io/) to implement it in a mobile app. It has components in SWIFT and React Native. I'm a junior Flutter developer, we are making a mobile app using the Dart programming language. Is there any way to use Dynamic Layer ui-kit in Flutter apps?